# DB schema owner issue with powershell script

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

I'm learning powershell scripting and wrote a simple script to restore a sql database from a backup file. The restore works great, however now I need the script to remove a couple of users from the newly restored DB and add them back. This is no problem if they are not listed as the owners of any schema in that particular DB.

The issue I'm having is if they are listed as a schema owner then my script will throw this exception

```
Exception calling "Drop" with "0" argument(s): "Drop failed for User 'MyUser'. "
At line:1 char:1
+ $user.Drop()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedOperationException
```

I have tried this code to change the owner of the schema to dbo but I still get the exception. The strange thing is if I inspect the schema details in powershell after I change the owner I do see the owner as dbo, but if I inspect the schema owner in sql server management studio the owner is still the old owner, even after refreshing the DB.

```
PS E:\MyScripts> $server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") "(local)"
PS E:\MyScripts> $server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") "(local)"
PS E:\MyScripts> $db = $server.Databases["MyDB"]
PS E:\MyScripts> $sch = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Schema -argumentlist $db, "MySchema"
PS E:\MyScripts> $sch.Owner = "[dbo]"
```

The entire script looks something like this

```
#load assemblies
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null

#Need SmoExtended for backup
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | Out-Null

$server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") "(local)"

$db = $server.Databases["MyDB"];
$user = $db.Users["MyUser"];
$sch = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Schema -argumentlist $db, "MySchema"
$sch.Owner = "[dbo]";
$user.Drop();
```

**SOLUTION THAT WORKED FOR ME**
After some playing around with the script and the suggestion below I figured out that the issue was I wasn't calling .Alter() on the schema after updating the owner. I had some trouble initially using .Alter() because I was trying to create a "New-Object" for the database schema when one already existed. So the solution for me was

```
PS E:\MyScripts> [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
PS E:\MyScripts>
PS E:\MyScripts> [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
PS E:\MyScripts> [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-Null
PS E:\MyScripts> [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | Out-Null
PS E:\MyScripts>
PS E:\MyScripts> $server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") "(local)"
PS E:\MyScripts> $db = $server.Databases["MyDB"]
PS E:\MyScripts> $db = $server.Databases["MyExistingSchema"]
PS E:\MyScripts> $db.Schemas["Cadence"].Owner = "MyUser"
PS E:\MyScripts> $db.Schemas["Cadence"].Alter()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling alter method on the $sch object after setting the new owner:

```
$sch.Owner = "[dbo]"
$sch.Alter()
```

Comment: `Exception calling "Alter" with "0" argument(s): "Alter failed for Schema 'MySchema'. "
At E:\MyScripts\AddDBLogins.ps1:94 char:1
+ $sch.Alter()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedOperationException
`

Comment: I've found this [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162204.aspx) after I posted my question, however it seems like this is adding a new schema not altering a new one. Even when trying to follow the example in the documentation line for line I get the same error as above.

Comment: Correction, I just disconnected from sql server management studio and re-ran the documentation script line for line and it worked so I'm thinking it has something to do with a permissions issue on the schema vs the local user I'm access it from.

Comment: Thanks Chad, I gave you the answer because you pointed me in the right direction and you are correct, I needed to use .Alter(). I complete explanation of what worked for me is above in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Owned schema from one user to another user

```
$srv = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $servername
$database = $srv.Databases[$dbname]
$sch = $database.Schemas["db_owner"]
$sch.Owner = "dbo"
$sch.Alter()
```